# Make hyperref take pdfinfo from \title and \author

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I once read about an option for `hyperref` that automatically takes the info provided via the standard `\author` and `\title`, and puts it into the `pdfinfo`. Now I want to implement it in my template and can't find it anywhere in the `hyperref` manual nor anywhere else.

Did I dream about this or can someone help me out here?

(A similar, but more general question: [Is hyperref really the best way to add metadata to a TeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/is-hyperref-really-the-best-way-to-add-metadata-to-a-tex-file))

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The option is `pdfusetitle`. It is described in the hyperref README file.

Comment: Ah, that's where I saw it, thanks! For some reason it only seems to work as `\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}` and not as `\hypersetup{pdfusetitle}` though.

Comment: @doncherry: Yeah, a few options are like that. I suppose they require special arrangements to be made at load time...

Comment: As of April 2012, this option is not described in the hyperref manual. Any reason for that?

Comment: This doesn't work (anymore?). It gives the following warning: `Package hyperref Warning: Option \`pdfusetitle' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 44.` and has no effect (in that the PDF has no title or author set automatically).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The warning only says, that `pdfusetitle` was set too late. It needs to be set at package loading time (`\usepackage`).

Answer (score 26):

You could also use

```
 \makeatletter
 \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title},pdfauthor={\@author}}
 \makeatother
```

(edit: makeat* pointed out by Joseph Wright)

Comment: This needs `\makeatletter`, of course.

Comment: This might be a nice alternative if `pdfusetitle` fails -- the readme says it "tries to derive the values", so a failure for whatever reason apparently can't be excluded.

Comment: @Joseph: Would `\makeatletter` be called before (and `\makeatother` after) `\hypersetup{...}` or separately for each argument? Considering that I have up to nine or ten arguments for `\hypersetup` and considering how mighty and thus dangerous `hyperref` is, it might cause conflicts if placed around the entire command?

Comment: @doncherry: `\makeatletter` before `\hypersetup` and `\makeatother` after it.

Comment: @doncherry the readme is right, `pdfusetitle` will fail if you have any non ASCII character in your title or author name, with the error ** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16... That's why this method, with your addendum is the best.

Comment: This works only before `\begin{document}`, doesn't it?

Comment: There's also the `authoraftertitle` package but I somehow can't get it to work.