# Referring to Title of Document in Hypersetup

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I started a document like this to avoid having to write the title and author twice:

```
\title{The Document's Title}
\author{My Name}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    bookmarks=true
}
```

I read about using `\@title` to insert the document's title. However, it doesn't work. Instead, my PDF's title (the text in the window bar of the PDF viewer) is now "title".

If you want a complete document which exhibits the problem for testing, you can use this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{The Document's Title}
\author{My Name}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    bookmarks=true
}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should make (small) but complete examples. Snippets can not be tested easily.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I assumed it's so basic that that's not necessary. I added it.

Comment: `\@title` is the `\@` command followed by `title` in a document unless you use `\makeatletter` which makes `@` a letter

Comment: You need to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17254/4012. But it’s easier to use the option `pdfusetitle`. Essentially, this question seems to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17218/4012, so I’d propose closing it as that? Edit: Why doesn’t tex.sx show me new comments until I submitted mine ... ?

Comment: @UTF-8: get the habit to provide a complete example. May it be necessary or not it makes testing more easier http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6258/2388

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\@title` and `\@author` have `@` in their names, therefore `\makeatletter` is needed:

```
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle=\@title,
  pdfauthor=\@author,
}
\makeatother
```

An alternative is option `pdfusetitle`, which tries to automatically catch `\@title` and `\@author`:

```
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
```

Comment: I tried using the `pdfusetitle` option but it didn't work. It didn't put the title nor the author into the PDF. Since the title was then empty, PDF viewers didn't show a title as meta information and put the file name into the window bar. However, using `\makeatletter` worked and put both the author and the title information into to PDF's meta data. Thank you!

Comment: @UTF-8 The option `pdfusetitle` hooks into `\maketitle`, which is missing here.

Comment: In my document, `\maketitle` is the very first command after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @UTF-8 Without further details, MWE, it's guessing in the dark. Anyway, `pdfusetitle` is just a convenience option. Either it works or not, there are other ways of setting the title and author in the PDF document.