# How to plugin values into hypersetup one at a time

Tags: macros

So I have this in my document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfborder=0 0 0,
  pdfinfo={
    Author={Me},
    Creator={Me},
    Title={The title},
    Subject={A subject},
    Producer={LaTeX}
  }
}
```

How do I set each of these values one at a time (author, creator, title, etc.) and plug them in? So this is how I would like to use it:

```
\documentclass{foo}

\fooauthor{Me}
\footitle{A Title}
...
```

Then plug it in somehow in the `.cls` file or some `.sty` file:

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfborder=0 0 0,
  pdfinfo={
    Author={@fooauthor},
    Creator={@fooauthor},
    Title={@footitle}
    ...
  }
}
```

How to do something like this?

Comment: Something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17254/4736 ?

Answer (score 2):

You did not state anything about whatsoever TeX-extensions may be used (ε-TeX, `\expanded`, ...).

Therefore my first example doesn't make use of whatsoever extensions at all.

Instead with that example a lot of `\romannumeral0`-expansion takes place.

The gist of `\romannumeral0`-expansion is:

`\romannumeral` gathers digits and a terminating space-token for finding the number to convert to roman notation.
**Expansion** of expandable tokens **is not suppressed** but triggered when seeking for more digits or the terminating space-token of the number to convert.
A space-token terminating the sequence of digits that forms the number to convert is silently discarded.
In case the **number** to convert is **not positive**, `\romannumeral0` will silently just swallow the digit-sequence that forms the number and **not deliver any token** in return.

Therefore you can nicely (ab?)use `\romannumeral` for triggering a lot of expansion- and argument-exchanging-work during the search for more digits or a space-token that terminates the digit-sequence as long as it is ensured that in the end the number found is not positive.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%    

% Be aware that two consecutive hashes in the definition-text of a macro will be collapsed 
% into a single hash within the result of expanding that macro.
% Therefore something must be done for having hashes doubled within the macros that serve as
% place-holders for values of variables:
\newcommand\definemacrowithhashdoubling[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
     \expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
  }{%
    \toks@{#2}%
    \@ifdefinable#1{\edef#1{\the\toks@}}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand\foopdfborder[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foopdfborder{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooauthor[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooauthor{#1}}%
\newcommand\foocreator[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foocreator{#1}}%
\newcommand\footitle[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@footitle{#1}}%
\newcommand\foosubject[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foosubject{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooproducer[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooproducer{#1}}%

% \DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList delivers keyval-list for \hypersetup according
% to the definitions of \@foopdfborder, \@fooauthor, \@foocreator, \@footitle, 
% \@foosubject and \@fooproducer.
%
% Due to \romannumeral0-/\Exchange-expansion-trickery, the result is delivered
% after triggering two expansion-steps/after two "hits" with \expandafter:
%
\newcommand\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \csname @\@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{%
      \@ifundefined{@foocreator}{%
        \@ifundefined{@footitle}{%
          first%
        }{second}%
      }{second}%
    }{second}oftwo\endcsname{ }{%
      \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\romannumeral0%
        \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@footitle}{ %
          }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@footitle}}{ Title=},}%
        }{%
          \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@foocreator}{ %
            }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@foocreator}}{ Creator=},}%
          }{%
            \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
              \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{ %
              }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@fooauthor}}{ Author=},}%
            }{%
              \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
                \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@foosubject}{ %
                }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@foosubject}}{ Subject=},}%
              }{%
                \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
                  \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@fooproducer}{ %
                  }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@fooproducer}}{ Producer=},}%
                }{ }%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }}{ pdfinfo=},%
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0\@ifundefined{@foopdfborder}{ %
      }{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\@foopdfborder}}{ pdfborder=},}%
    }{ }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\foopdfborder{0 0 0}
\fooauthor{Me}
\foocreator{Me}
\footitle{The title}
\foosubject{A subject}
\fooproducer{LaTeX}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList}%

\show\test

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hypersetup
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList}%

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

In case ε-TeX-extensions which bring along the `\unexpanded`-primitive are available, you can combine `\edef` and `\unexpanded` for defining a temporary macro and passing its expansion to `\hypersetup`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%    

% Be aware that two consecutive hashes in the definition-text of a macro will be collapsed 
% into a single hash within the result of expanding that macro.
% Therefore something must be done for having hashes doubled within the macros that serve as
% place-holders for values of variables:
\newcommand\definemacrowithhashdoubling[2]{\@ifdefinable#1{\edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}}}}%

\newcommand\foopdfborder[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foopdfborder{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooauthor[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooauthor{#1}}%
\newcommand\foocreator[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foocreator{#1}}%
\newcommand\footitle[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@footitle{#1}}%
\newcommand\foosubject[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foosubject{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooproducer[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooproducer{#1}}%

% \DefineMyHyperSetupTempMacro defines the macro \MyHyperSetupTempMacro
% to expand to a keyval-list for \hypersetup according
% to the definitions of \@foopdfborder, \@fooauthor, \@foocreator, \@footitle, 
% \@foosubject and \@fooproducer.
%
\newcommand\DefineMyHyperSetupTempMacro{%
  \edef\MyHyperSetupTempMacro{%
    \@ifundefined{@foopdfborder}{}{pdfborder={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foopdfborder}},}%
    \csname @\@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{%
      \@ifundefined{@foocreator}{%
        \@ifundefined{@footitle}{%
          first%
        }{second}%
      }{second}%
    }{second}oftwo\endcsname{}{%
      pdfinfo={%
        \@ifundefined{@fooproducer}{}{Producer={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@fooproducer}},}%
        \@ifundefined{@foosubject}{}{Subject={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foosubject}},}%
        \@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{}{Author={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@fooauthor}},}%
        \@ifundefined{@foocreator}{}{Creator={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foocreator}},}%
        \@ifundefined{@footitle}{}{Title={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@footitle}},}%
      },%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\foopdfborder{0 0 0}
\fooauthor{Me}
\foocreator{Me}
\footitle{The title}
\foosubject{A subject}
\fooproducer{LaTeX}

\DefineMyHyperSetupTempMacro

\show\MyHyperSetupTempMacro

\expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\MyHyperSetupTempMacro}%

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

In case besides the ε-TeX-extensions the `\expanded`-primitive is available also, you can combine `\unexpanded` with `\expanded` and do without temporary macro—this is a shorter implementation of the first example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%    

% Be aware that two consecutive hashes in the definition-text of a macro will be collapsed 
% into a single hash within the result of expanding that macro.
% Therefore something must be done for having hashes doubled within the macros that serve as
% place-holders for values of variables:
\newcommand\definemacrowithhashdoubling[2]{\@ifdefinable#1{\edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}}}}%

\newcommand\foopdfborder[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foopdfborder{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooauthor[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooauthor{#1}}%
\newcommand\foocreator[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foocreator{#1}}%
\newcommand\footitle[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@footitle{#1}}%
\newcommand\foosubject[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@foosubject{#1}}%
\newcommand\fooproducer[1]{\definemacrowithhashdoubling\@fooproducer{#1}}%

% \DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList delivers keyval-list for \hypersetup according
% to the definitions of \@foopdfborder, \@fooauthor, \@foocreator, \@footitle, 
% \@foosubject and \@fooproducer.
%
% Due to \romannumeral0-/\Exchange-expansion-trickery, the result is delivered
% after triggering two expansion-steps/after two "hits" with \expandafter:
%
\newcommand\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{%
    \expanded{%
      \@ifundefined{@foopdfborder}{}{pdfborder={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foopdfborder}},}%
      \csname @\@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{%
        \@ifundefined{@foocreator}{%
          \@ifundefined{@footitle}{%
            first%
          }{second}%
        }{second}%
      }{second}oftwo\endcsname{}{%
        pdfinfo={%
          \@ifundefined{@fooproducer}{}{Producer={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@fooproducer}},}%
          \@ifundefined{@foosubject}{}{Subject={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foosubject}},}%
          \@ifundefined{@fooauthor}{}{Author={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@fooauthor}},}%
          \@ifundefined{@foocreator}{}{Creator={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@foocreator}},}%
          \@ifundefined{@footitle}{}{Title={\unexpanded\expandafter{\@footitle}},}%
        },%
      }%
    }%
  }{ }%
}%
\makeatother

\foopdfborder{0 0 0}
\fooauthor{Me}
\foocreator{Me}
\footitle{The title}
\foosubject{A subject}
\fooproducer{LaTeX}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList}%

\show\test

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hypersetup
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\DeliverHyperSetupKeyValList}%

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```