# Hyperref 'pdftitle' and 'pdfauthor' with custom title & author command

Tags: hyperref

I want to set `hyperref` to use my custom command for `title` & `author`.

```
\documentclass{article} % or report or book

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\titlul}[1]{%
 \newcommand*{\@titlul}{#1}
}

\newcommand*{\autor}[1]{%
 \newcommand*{\@autor}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\dotitle}{%
 \begingroup
 \thispagestyle{empty}%
 \centering
 \vspace*{1cm}
 \ifcsname @titlul\endcsname
  {\Large\bfseries\sffamily \@titlul\par}\smallskip
 \fi
 \ifcsname @autor\endcsname
  {\large\sffamily \@autor\par}\vspace{.1cm}
 \fi
 \vspace{1cm}
 \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@titlul},pdfauthor={\@autor}}
% error 
%  Undefined control sequence.
% <argument> \@titlul
% l.40 ...tup{pdftitle={\@titlul},pdfauthor={\@autor}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/make-hyperref-take-pdfinfo-from-title-and-author
\makeatother

\titlul{Title here}
\autor{Author here}
\date{\today}

% start document
\begin{document}
\dotitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: well you are calling \hypersetup before you actually define the title. So what do you expect here?

Comment: Isn't \titlul{Title here} defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this setup.

**(Sumatra)**

[image: a]

**(Adobe Reader)**

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article} % or report or book

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titlul}[1]{%
    \newcommand{\@titlul}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily #1}
}

\newcommand{\autor}[1]{%
    \newcommand{\@autor}{\large\sffamily #1}}


\newcommand{\dotitle}{%
    \begingroup
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \centering
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \ifcsname @titlul\endcsname%
    { \@titlul\par}\smallskip%
    \fi
    \ifcsname @autor\endcsname%
    { \@autor\par}\vspace{.1cm}
    \fi%
    \vspace{1cm}
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\titlul{Title here}
\autor{Author here}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\titlul\ },
    pdfauthor={\autor\ Copyright \textcopyright\ \number\year\  },
    pdfsubject={Subject I, Subject II},
    pdfkeywords={keyOne; keyTwo; keyThree},
    pdfcreator={Simon Dispa},
} % Set up 


% start document
\begin{document}
    \dotitle
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me why putting `titlul{bla}` & `autor{blabla}` on last position  gives me error and above `hyperref` package, not?

Comment: @Mafsi I am sorry but I do not understand the question. The setup of the package are different. For example, the spaces are important.

Comment: Please run this code and note that I put `\titlul` & `autor` below `hyperreff`
https://pastebin.com/VwtnNVTJ I get 
```./dispa.tex:38: Undefined control sequence.
\titlul #1->\newcommand {\@titlul
                                  }{\Large \bfseries \sffamily #1}
l.38 }
     % Set up
?
```

Comment: @Mafsi I think you already discover the problem: `\titlul{Title here}` and  `\autor{Author here}` should be place before `\hypersetup`.

Comment: Thanks, but as the first question I asked, I want to know why.

Comment: @Mafsi     `hyperref` is not a passive package that loads and adds some commands that you may or may not use. Instead, when loaded, many commands of LaTeX and other packages are redefined and the `.aux` file is also changed. 

The general rule is to load it last. (There are exceptions: see
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before`)

In your case, it can't do its job if `\title` and `\author` weren't previously defined as the error message indicates