# hyperref vs hyperxmp

Tags: hyperref, metadata, hyperxmp

What is the better package to use in embedding metadata, `hyperref` or `hyperxmp`? Which has a wider range or can be extended further? (Like: Does using `xmp` metadata more reliable than just embedding a simple metadata?)

Comment: Related: [Is `hyperref` really the best way to add metadata to a TeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5958/5764)

Comment: `hyperxmp` relies on, and gives instructions to, `hyperref`, so you need to use `hyperref` either way.  `hyperxmp` is not easily extensible; `xmpincl` is more extensible, but much less user-friendly.  XMP is an ISO standard, so that counts for something, but I suppose it depends on what your actual needs and expectations are....

Answer (score 1):

The two packages differ heavily so there is no «better» or «worse».

1. The bigger and older and more low level `hyperref` mainly is about creating links in PDF. It can also add some metadata that are `Document Info`, not `XMP`. But the former  are more and more being replaced by XMP metadata.
2. The smaller and newer and more high level `hyperxmp` does *not* interfere with links. It *mainly* adds `XMP` metadata to the PDF. hyperxmp is built on top of hyperref. hyperxmp can use the interface of hyperref: `\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}` will additionally create an XMP entry called `dc:title` when you `\usepackage{hyperxmp}`.
   But hyperxmp will also do some higher level stuff. When you just say `\Title{mytitle}` in a document hyperxmp (if loaded) will translate this to `\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}` thus leading to a Document Info *and* XMP metadata. The newest version will even load `hyperref` if you don't to it yourself.