# Exporting a tagged PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata

I use LaTeX for typesetting daily document. These include correspondence with patients, certificates etc. Is there any way I can tags (or keywords) for running subsequent searching from inside LaTeX markup? For example, if I have a patient with Hepatitis C, I can just tag it from within, so that when I search Hepatitis C next time, all PDF files can be detected easily.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate at all...

Comment: @Vaibhav How do you conduct a "search"? Any special local search engine, or does your OS index the folder with your files? Please describe your plan / wishes / nightmares...

Comment: @Keks Dose     I  use OS dependent search. Though acrobat reader allow search within the directory containing pdf files. Adding metadata might help me rapid and accurate search. The problem when I use operating system based search is that I get many results which are irrelevant as eg many patients are advised HCV test, so files contain the word hcv. But when I search, I need only those who are positive.

Comment: I can imagine a solution where you add metadata (via, e.g., `hyperref`), which could be combined with the commandline programs/utilities (on *nix systems at least) `find` and `pdfinfo`.  I would think Macs could do that too; and maybe(?) on Windows if you have something like `cygwin` installed....

Answer (score 2):

You can add metadata with `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfkeywords={Hepatitis C}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is not always needed for adding PDF metadata. See [Is `hyperref` really the best way to add metadata to a TeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5958/5764)

Comment: @Werner Indeed! And the general question, wether PDF metadata is the right approach to the issue at hand is not touched at all...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to TeX. You can add metadata, tags, whatever to a PDF, using `\pdfinfo{}`, hyperref or whatever.

The trouble is, how to search for it: as far as I know, there is no search engine which can be limited to tags or keywords in PDF. E.g. Windows obviously has no support for tags, see here: https://superuser.com/q/602536

There are some addons: http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/pdfpropertyextension , but I have not tested, nor downloaded.