# How do I use titling with hyperref and unicode?

Tags: hyperref, unicode, metadata, titling

I want to use the `titling` package to access title and author with `\thetitle` and `\theauthor`, which I want to include in the PDF metadata with `hyperref`. But both title and author can contain umlauts which seems to mess up the metadata.
My MWE is such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\author{äää}
\date{\today}
\title{üüüü}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{
   \hypersetup{
      pdftitle          = {\thetitle},
      pdfauthor         = {\theauthor},
   }
}

\begin{document}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

But when inspecting the metadata, this is the result:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load `inputenc` **before** `titling`, to make it aware about the unicode settings etc, otherwise it uses the wrong encoding for `\author{äää}` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\author{äää}
\date{\today}
\title{üüüü}


\RequirePackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}


\AtBeginDocument{
   \hypersetup{
      pdftitle          = {\thetitle},
      pdfauthor         = {\theauthor},
   }
}

\begin{document}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]