# XeLaTeX version of \pdfinfoomitdate (or method to accomplish the same)?

Tags: xetex, date, xdvipdfmx

According to:
[Can I suppress Date Created metadata field in output of pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327440/78866)
and
[Reproducible LaTeX builds - compile to a file which always hashes to the same value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313605/78866)

pdfTeX (versions ≥1.40.17) support the use of `\pdfinfoomitdate` to suppress the `/CreationDate` and `/ModDate` from begin written to the PDF.

I have searched for an equivalent method for XeLaTeX and XeTeX, but have not found anything.  Did I miss it somewhere (if so, please present it here and point to where it is in the documentation)?  Is there some alternative approach to accomplishing the same thing?  Or is it not currently possible at all for XeLaTeX?

In case it is relevant, I am using `xdvipdfmx` as the output driver.

Comment: Good question, but I'm afraid the answer is “unless `xdvipdfmx` gets modified, no”.

Comment: Alright, at least that explains why I couldn't find it anywhere.  There is obviously some development with the pdfLaTeX drivers, but your comment suggests `xdvipdfmx` not so much.  Is there  place you can point me to maintainers/developers?  I'm not entirely clear if this is something generally handled via TUG or through something such as github or sourceforge (or basically not, due to a complete lack of development).