# \pdfinfoomitdate causes undefined control sequence

Tags: pdf

I run  `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2020.12.22)` and try to compile

```
\documentclass{article}

\pdfinfoomitdate 1

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

with TeXStudio and get an error `Undefined control sequence. \pdfinfoomitdate`. Do I miss something in my installation (on Windows)?

Comment: I'm not sure but the command seems to be `pdflatex` only, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362366/xelatex-version-of-pdfinfoomitdate-or-method-to-accomplish-the-same

Comment: Ahhh... I see. Then I close it. I thought in `pdfprivacy` is compatible with LuaTeX but obviously not. Which means I'll stuck to the cryptic `\pdfvariable suppressoptionalinfo 767` flag of   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225790/48642

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace `pdfprivacy`, add the following line to the preamble instead, which will have the same effect:

```
\pdfvariable suppressoptionalinfo 767
```

(h/t [LeO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48642/leo))

For more details, see the following SO post: [Reproducible LaTeX builds - compile to a file which always hashes to the same value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229605/reproducible-latex-builds-compile-to-a-file-which-always-hashes-to-the-same-va)

Comment: That's the same answer as I have given ...