# Declaring multiple authors in pdfauthor from hyperref

Tags: hyperref

How do I typeset multiple authors with the `pdfauthor` option from the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package?

If I try

> `pdfauthor={A, B, and C}`

the names in the author field (when displayed in Adobe Reader) are surrounded by `"`;

> [image: output]

How do I get rit of the `"`s.

Comment: It's just the use of `,`... Hmmm...

Comment: @Werner I figured out just that a moment ago. `:)` Do you know how to get around this problem?

Comment: If I ask `pdfinfo`, I get no quotes. Nor Skim shows them. So it's a Reader quirk.

Comment: This may be viewer-dependent. See [`hyperref` “enquotes” metadata](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3708/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: @egreg: Removing the quotes when edited in Adobe Acrobat doesn't help, since Adobe Acrobat re-inserts them. So it must be dependent on the browser.